# MeteorJS: how to read stdin from the terminal?

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to **read stdin** from the terminal on a Meteor app? I want to run some prompts using [Node's readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html).

I tried the example at readline's page but I only get the prompt printed to the terminal without waiting for an answer:

```
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What do you think of node.js? ", function(answer) {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log("Thank you for your valuable feedback:", answer);

  rl.close();
});
```

This code works just fine in a plain NodeJS script.

Related tickets:

- https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-mcli/issues/6

Comment: Have you tried using `meteor shell`? It would allow you to do everything you want, and then some.

Comment: @AndrewMao `meteor shell` doesn't give me the ability to prompt the user on the terminal. This is needed for CLI apps, or to initially configure packages/apps.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this is possible for now. OP opened a related issue to MDG (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4836), which was subsequently closed.

The recommended way to write interactive command-line apps is to use Node directly.